# communicate from Apple watch simulator to iPhone device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, watchkit

I have a requirement where I need to start recording in Iphone device On button tap of Apple watch and stop recording when the same button is tapped again in Apple watch app. But since Apple watch is not available yet how can I test this functionality? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pair a real iPhone with the Watch Simulator. All testing has to be done using the Watch Simulator alongside the iPhone simulator.

Normally you would be able to test your desired functionality with the simulators, but if by "recording" you are referring to video recording, that would not be possible as the iPhone simulator does not have access to a camera.

This is an excellent use case for the need to pair the Watch Simulator with a real iPhone. Apple have been actively encouraging developers to submit their enhancement requests to http://bugreport.apple.com

Clearly, you will want to also test with the actual hardware as soon as it ships.

Answer (score 2):

In your watch app you need to use WKInterfaceController's method

```
+ (BOOL)openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error)) reply;
```

and catch it in your AppDelegate's method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
```

It is the only way for communication between watch app and main app

Comment: Hi @oxigen, Actually my question is that I want to know If I can test my above scenario by running the watch App on watch app simulator and have it communicate with my app on iPhone instead of iPhone simulator. I mean I want the app on watch simulator communicate with its paired app on real iphone instead of iphone simulator. As on  iphone simulator the camera functionality cannot be tested.

Answer (score 2):

Current version of the Xcode beta is not supporting of concurrent running of device, please go through the release document Xcode 6.2 beta 4 release notes in [downloads](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)

In the known issues section of release notes they clearly mentioned this,

> Running an iOS app and a WatchKit app concurrently in the Simulator
>   via Xcode is not supported. (18559453)

Answer (score 0):

Pairing ios device with a watch simulator is not possible

Comment: [This answer has already been given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949851/8881141) and with more explanation. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)